# Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory

Tags: php

There is no solution, as i have searched a lot on moving my uploaded image into directory  here is my php code :

```
<?php
  //Profile Image upload script
  if (isset($_FILES['profilepic'])) {
   if (((@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))&&(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["size"] < 1048576)) //1 Megabyte
  {
   $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
   $dir = "userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name";
   mkdir($dir);
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name".$_FILES["profile‌​pic"]["name"]);
    $profile_pic_name = $_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"];
    echo $profile_pic_name;
    $profile_pic_query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users2 SET profile_pic='$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name' WHERE username='$user'");

  }
  else
  {
      $msg5 =  "Invailid File! Your image must be no larger than 1MB and it must be either a .jpg, .jpeg, .png or .gif";
  }
  }

?>
```

but when I try to upload image,it creates the random folder in userdata/profile_pics but it doesn't move the file into random folder directory i have also created a custom php.ini file with file_uploads = On, but i recieve the following warning when i submit the form :-

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/rahulkapoor90/public_html/note.php on line 26

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpO592dd' to 'userdata/profile_pics/zAGC9wOhVyoe3R5' in /home/rahulkapoor90/public_html/note.php on line 26
/tmp/phpO592dd

Comment: Think you are missing a '/' like so: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/{$_FILES["profile‌​pic"]["name"]}");`

Comment: @Twisty it is still unable to move file to the directory.

Comment: by the way, my userdata/profile_pics is in public_html folder in cpanel.

Comment: Assuming that when PHP creates the directory, it allows Write?

Comment: yes, it is in 0755 mode

Comment: Try adding the `key` element: `$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"][0]`

Comment: nope, it is still not working.

Comment: It should be working with `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"], $dir . "/" .$_FILES["profile‌​pic"]["name"]);` That's very strange. Can you var_dump before you perform the move?

Comment: what should i var_dump, and is still not workn

Comment: I would `var_dump($_FILES)` to see if all those details are correct. The error also suggests you are passing just `'userdata/profile_pics/zAGC9wOhVyoe3R5'` as the 2nd argument and not `'userdata/profile_pics/zAGC9wOhVyoe3R5/filename.ext'`

Comment: Also can you update your code examples with what you're currently using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75324/discussion-between-rahul-kapoor-and-twisty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this error, in my case it was a permissions issue. I re-factored some legacy code and checked the wrong directory for permissions and instead kept getting this misleading error message.

Answer (score 0):

Wasted few hours to get the correct cause. You can try 2 things

**Verify your destination folder**

```
`$destdir="YOUR-COMPLETE-DESTINATION-FOLDER/uploads/";

if(is_dir($destdir) && is_writable($destdir))
    {echo "<strong>UPLOAD DIRECTORY EXIST & WRITABLE</strong>";}
else 
    {echo "<strong>ISSUE WITH UPLOAD DIRECTORY</strong>";}`
```

**Confirm 2nd parameter of `move_uploaded_file` is a file name NOT A DIRECTORY NAME**

In my case this turned to be the issue
    `if(move_uploaded_file($tempname,"$destdir/".$_FILES['profilepic']['name']"))
        {echo 'FILE UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY';}
    else 
        {echo "FAILED TO UPLOAD";}`